# TypeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pickle

I have a huge dataset stored in .hdf5 file that I am trying to split to groups. the .hdf5 file contain an array shaped as `(2 555 904 x 1024 x 2)`
a small example of my code is the following:

```
import pickle
import h5py
import numpy as np

f = h5py.File('RML_2018.hdf5', 'r')
# Assembling M-PSK dataset 
PSK_32 = f['X'][0:106496]
PSK_OQ = f['X'][638976:745472]
PSK_2  = f['X'][851968:958464]
PSK_8  = f['X'][958464:1064960]
PSK_16 = f['X'][1277952:1384448]
PSK_Q  = f['X'][2023424:2129920]

M_PSK  = np.concatenate([PSK_32, PSK_OQ, PSK_2, PSK_8, PSK_16, PSK_Q])
print('shape of M_PSK array :',M_PSK.shape)

del PSK_32
del PSK_OQ
del PSK_2
del PSK_8
del PSK_16
del PSK_Q

with open('Data/M_PSK.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(M_PSK, f, protocol=4)

# Assembling M-APSK dataset
APSK_16 = f['X'][106496:212992]
APSK_32 = f['X'][532480:638976]
APSK_64 = f['X'][1384448:1490944]
APSK_128= f['X'][1597440:1703936]

M_APSK  = np.concatenate([APSK_16, APSK_32, APSK_64, APSK_128])
print('shape of M_APSK array :',M_APSK.shape)

del APSK_16
del APSK_32
del APSK_64
del APSK_128

with open('Data/M_APSK.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(M_APSK, f, protocol=4)
```

So as you can see I am reading chunks of the original dataset, concatenate them then delete to save memory and finally dump the concatenated array to a .pkl file

The first part was ok. but then I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nechi/PycharmProjects/CNN_MR_v2/cnn.py", line 28, in <module>
    APSK_16 = f['X'][106496:212992]
TypeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object is not subscriptable
```

Could anybody tell me whats is this error message and am I getting it ?
And how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was that I opened the .hdf file and .pkl file with the same name `f`

```
f = h5py.File('RML_2018.hdf5', 'r')
```

and

```
with open('Data/M_PSK.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(M_PSK, f, protocol=4)
```

which created a confusion, So I had to choose different names for the files and it works.